# Stop kdevelop from automatically inserting include files

Tags: kdevelop

Kdevelop keeps automatically inserting

```
 #include <../../home/blah/tmp/llvm35/lib/Target/ARM/ARMInstrFormats.td>
```

and other similar includes at what feels like random times into my code, causing compile errors. I'm guessing this is some autocomplete script gone rogue. Anyone have any idea how to disable it?

Answer (score 0):

Issue tracked at: https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=315505

Which KDevelop issue are you using? This should be fixed in KDevelop 4.7.2.